# Discrete math counting

Tags: combinatorics

A password is a string of 8 characters taken from the alphabet (that is, the
set of 26 characters {a, b, c, ..., x, y, z}), the set of 10 digits {0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} and the set
of 5 special characters {!, @, #, ∗, +}.

How many unique passwords are there where you can repeat characters and have at
least 2 digits and at least 1 special character?

How would I use the product rule here, also would this be the inclusion-exclusion rule where I get the set of all unique passwords (41^8) then subtract sets that contain 0 & 1 digits & special characters?

Answer (score 2):

$A_1$ = passwords with no digits.

$A_2$ = passwords with exactly 1 digit.

$A_3$ = passwords with no special characters.

the answer is equal to $41^8 - |A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3|$.

the inclusion-exclusion rule tells us that
$$|A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3| = |A_1|+|A_2|+|A_3|-|A_1\cap A_2| - |A_2\cap A_3| - |A_1\cap A_3| + |A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|$$

thus $|A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3|$ is equal to
$$31^8 + {10\choose1}{8\choose 1}\times 31^7 + 36^8 - 0 -{10\choose1}{8\choose1}\times26^7- 26^8+0$$
so the answer is $41^8 - (31^8+80\times31^7+36^8-80\times26^7-26^8) = 2961287034000$.

Comment: The expression gives $2961287034000$.